# How to reconcile number of photos and disk space used on MacBook Pro vs new iPad Pro

Tags: macos, ipad, finder, photos

I have a newly set up iPad pro, 3rd gen, 11 inch that we got new and set up via wireless side by side transfer.  Upon plugging it in to MacBook pro Big Sur 11.6, i noticed that the pictures folder on the MacBook shows (left side below on screen shot of Get Info) 34.16 gb and 13,085 items while the iPad (right side of screen shot) shows 18.48 GB and the iPad has 6,695 photos and 71 videos showing synced from the computer.  I have deleted the synced photos, soft reset ipad and restart MacBook and re-synced with same results as shown below.

Questions:

Which is right?  Why the difference?  How do i reconcile the difference?

I have compared manually almost all of the computer folders to the iPad synced folders and have only found about 5 missing picture and .mov files for a total of about 200mb.  thank you

[image: new]

In the photo folder on the Mac I sync with there are "iPhoto library", "iPod photo cache", "Photo booth library" and "photos library folders".  If I exclude those and "get info" on the remainder of the folders, the no. and sizes matches almost exactly to what is being synced to the iPad.  The culprit for the greatest difference is the iPod photo cache for about 15gig.  The 4 folders are included in the total on the Mac but do not sync to the iPad, hence the difference.

Comment: If you open an image on the ipad and press the info button (lowercase letter i in a circle) it will have the file size (I believe this requires iOS 15). Compare the file size to the same file on your computer and see if it matches.

Comment: I did that and did find some that were different , say, few hundreds kb to 1mb. But not enough to account for 16gb. I have also deleted all pic from iPad and soft reset the device, restarted computer and re-synced with same results as above.

Comment: My point is that if they're different it could be compressing everything just a little bit, or something

Comment: got that - but how to know for sure?  Apple cant say.  Also, why would the file count be 6 thousand files on iPad and computer shows oner 13 thousand pictures??  In comparing the folders manually( most of them) they seem to all contain the same number of pictures, so why the difference?

Comment: Without actually counting all the files it's impossible to say where the issue is, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In the photo folder on the Mac I sync with there are iPhoto library, iPod photo cache, Photo booth library and photos library folders.  If I exclude those and "get info" on the remainder of the folders, the no. and sizes matches almost exactly to what is being synced.  The culprit for the greatest difference is the iPod photo cache for about 15gig.  The 4 folders are included in the total but do not sync to the iPad, here the difference.